# Open BootstrapDialog without block the entire page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-dialog

Is there any way to use the BootstrapDialog without make the other components from a html page unavailable? In my application I have an dashboard where each link should open in a window (in this moment I trying BootstrapDialog), and when I am open one I don't want this block me to open others.

**UPDATE**

I still working in the code, but still not working the way I want. What I have now is this:

```
function load_page(url) {
    var responseText = '<div></div>';
    $(responseText).load(url);
    var title_text = $(responseText).attr("title").text();
    var message_text = $(responseText).attr("body").text();
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: $(title_text),
        message: $(message_text),
        draggable: true
    });
}
```

Here I want only a way of make the dialog don't block the page. This code is handled in other topic.

Comment: Could you share some code? Added the bootstrap-dialog tag, since I guess it is what you are using, not "native" bootstrap modal. Bootstrap dialog is just a wrapper for bootstrap modals.

Comment: added an update with code I have so far.

Comment: You are saying without a modal?

Comment: kind of yes. I want something like a popup window (like the ones we open with window.open() using javascript ), but with the style of the BootstrapDialog.

Comment: @KleberMota you may consider using tooltip feature of Bootstrap with binding it to document and setting it open on click.

Comment: do you can indicate any link showing how to do this?

Comment: @KleberMota Look at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips . I'm not sure if this will fit to your problem, but you will need something like this.

Comment: Sorry to say, but you cant! Bootstrap3 Dialog forces the backdrop as static and sets the modal class to fixed, filling the entire screen. You can remove backdrop, but then there still is .modal. Manipulating .modal after the dialog is shown gives some ugly results. There is to much hardcoded / static settings in bootstrap dialog to achive what you want. It would be much easier if you just used bootstrap modals themselves.